# C++ C4716 Beginner error. Understand the error conecpt but not sure how to make the program work

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm currently working on a program for one of my classes that goes like so:

```
#include <iostream>        // std::cout
using namespace std;
#include <windows.h>    // SetConsoleCursorPosition(HANDLE,COORD)
#include <conio.h>        // _getch()

struct Vector2
{
    int x, y;
    Vector2() :
        x(0), y(0)
    {}
    Vector2(int x, int y)
    {
        x = x;
        y = y;
    }
    bool is(int a_x, int a_y)
    {
        if (a_x == x, a_y==y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

class Entity //new  data class
{
public:
    Entity(int x,int y, char i)
    {
        pos.x = x;
        pos.y = y;
        icon = i;
    }
    void setX(int x)
    {
        pos.x = x;
    }
    int getX()
    {
        pos.x;
    }
    void setY(int y)
    {
        pos.y = y;
    }
    int getY()
    {
        pos.y;
    }
    void setIcon(char i)
    {
        icon = i;
    }
    char getIcon()
    {
        icon;
    }
private:
    Vector2 pos;
    char icon;
};

enum Gamestate
{
    RUNNING, WIN, LOST, USER_QUIT
};

void moveCursor(int x, int y)
{
    COORD c = { x,y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}


int main()
{
// player data
Entity e(3, 4, 1);

//game data
Gamestate state = RUNNING;
int input;
Vector2 size(20, 15);
Vector2 winPosition(size.x / 2, size.y / 2);
do
{ //draw the game world
    moveCursor(0, 0);
    for (int row = 0; row < size.x; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < size.y; col++)
        {
            cout << '.';
        } cout << '\n';
    }

    //draw player
    moveCursor(e.getX(), e.getY());
    cout << e.getIcon();
    //get input from user
    input = _getch();
    //process the user's input
    switch (input)
    {
    case 'w': //move up
        e.setY(e.getY() - 1);
        break;
    case 'a': //move left
        e.setX(e.getX() - 1);
        break;
    case 's': //move down
        e.setY(e.getY() + 1);
        break;
    case 'd': //move right
        e.setX(e.getX() + 1);
        break;
    case 27: //quit game
        state = USER_QUIT;
        break;
    }
    //show game state
    moveCursor(0, size.y + 1);
    switch (state)
    {
    case WIN:
        cout << "You WON! Congratulations!\n" ;
        break;
    case LOST:
        cout << "You lost...\n";
        break;
    }
    if (winPosition.is(e.getX(), e.getY()))
    {
        state = WIN;
    }
    else
    {
        state = LOST;
    }

} while (state == RUNNING);

//User input ESCAPE to quit program
cout << "Press ESCAPE to quit.\n";
while (_getch() != 27)
    ;

return 0;
}
```

The error occurs for `Entity::getY`,`Entity::getIcon`,`Entity::getX`
If I'm understanding the error correctly it's occurring because there are no values returned from main? But everything I try to do to fix it just leaves me with more errors then before.

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `get*` functions. `pos.x;` doesn't do _anything_.

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always include the actual errors in the question (and use comments to point out which line of the code they are on). Copy (as text) the complete and full output, and paste it into your question, without modifications.

Comment: Just noticed another error: ``if (a_x == x, a_y==y)`` Do you want both conditions to be true or either one? Use ``&&`` for the first one and ``||`` for the second one

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. Use the debugger

Comment: Since she references `conio.h`, she will need `/Wall` to enable all compiler warnings (you may want `/W3` instead, all - means - all for `cl.exe`)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems. In your get functions, you say you are supposed to return something, then never do. Another thing is in the constructor for `struct Vector2` you say

```
Vector2(int x, int y)
{
    x = x;
    y = y;
}
```

But this doesn't change the member variables. You need to specify which `x` and `y` you are trying to change by either changing the names or using `this`.